# PHP: How to read csv file in portions using AJAX request

Tags: php, ajax, csv, line

I am developing an application which has to read large CSV file and process data. It will be definitely not possible to make it in one request because processing the data also takes time, it is not just about reading.

So what I tried so far and what has been working well so far is the following:

```
// Open file
$handle = fopen($file, 'r');

// Move pointer to a place where it stopped last time
fseek($handle, $offset);

// Read limited line and process
for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
    // Get length of line for offset purposes
    $newlength = strlen(fgets($handle));

    // Move pointer back. fgets moves pointer so we move it back for fgetcsv to get that line again
    fseek($handle, $offset);

    $line = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $csv_delimiter);

    // Process data here

    // Save offset
    $offset += $newlength;
}
```

So the problem is here on this line:

```
$newlength = strlen(fgets($handle));
```

It fails when csv column has line breaks.

I also tried `$newlength = strlen(implode(';', fgetcsv($handle, 0, $csv_delimiter)));` but this does not always work. It usually fails for few characters. Probably quotations and end of line is not handled properly here.

All I need is to get length of csv line, not just single line, but csv line which might have line breaks within quotes.

Anybody has better solution?

Comment: I would send the job to a job queue and have a scheduler like cron process these jobs periodically from the command line. And send a notification to the appropriate person when a job is done.

Comment: This is not related to my question. Cron will come next. First I need to correct the script to process data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do one thing, create one mysql temporary table named "my_csv_data", and add one field in that table with all fields which are in csv file and extra add one "is_processed" with enum(0,1) default value '0'.

now import your all csv data in that sql table. it will never take more time for single insert.

now cerate one function/file which access my_csv_data table 10 or 100 records where is_processed='0' and process it and if process done successfully then update "is_processed" field to '1'.

now create one cronjob which hit that file/function. periodically.

using this way data will going to silently insert in your table without disturb/suffer any admin/front end user.

Answer (score 0):

i have codeignitor code where i uploading the csv file data and insert it into mysql database. hope this will help you

```
if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
                    {
                        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
                         while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
                         {

                                $data = array(
                                    'reedumption_code' => $emapData[0],
                                    'jb_note_id' =>$jbmoney_id,
                                    'jbmoney' =>$jbamount,
                                    'add_date'=>time(),
                                    'modify_date'=>time(),
                                    'user_id'=>0,
                                    'status'=>1,
                                    'assign_date'=>0,
                                    'del_status'=>1,
                                    'store_status'=>1
                                );
                            $this->load->model('currency_model');
                            $insertId = $this->currency_model->insertCSV($data);
                         }
                        fclose($file);
                        redirect('currency/add_currency?msg=Data Imported Successfully');
                    }
```